# How to combine uparrow and sim in Plain TeX?

Tags: symbols, plain-tex

I am trying to produce the following symbol with Plain (Xe)TeX:

[image: symbol]

I have tried `some text $\uparrow\llap{$\sim$}$ some text` but the spacing is wrong and `\sim` is not centered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\catcode`@=11

\def\upsim{\mathrel{\mathpalette\upsim@\relax}}
\def\upsim@#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \setbox\z@=\hbox{$\m@th#1\uparrow$}%
  \vphantom{\raise0.5\dp\z@\copy\z@}% fix the bounding box
  \ooalign{\hidewidth\raise0.5\dp\z@\box\z@\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1\sim$\cr}%
  \endgroup
}

\catcode`@=12

$x\upsim y_{x\upsim y}$

\bye
```

The `\uparrow` and `\sim` are superimposed, but the former is slightly raised to avoid clashes.

[image]

A generalization for the downarrow:

```
\catcode`@=11

\def\upsim{\mathrel{\mathpalette\arrowsim@{\uparrow\raise}}}
\def\downsim{\mathrel{\mathpalette\arrowsim@{\downarrow\lower}}}
\def\arrowsim@#1#2{\arrowsim@@#1#2}
\def\arrowsim@@#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \setbox\z@=\hbox{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \vphantom{#30.5\dp\z@\copy\z@}% fix the bounding box
  \ooalign{\hidewidth#30.5\dp\z@\box\z@\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1\sim$\cr}%
  \endgroup
}

\catcode`@=12

$x\upsim y_{x\upsim y}$

$x\downsim y_{x\downsim y}$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: I will study the code but the end result looks just perfect!